# How to write a RabbitMQ java client which can connect to IBM MQ AMQP channel

Tags: rabbitmq, ibm-mq, amqp

I have IBM MQ server with the latest feature of AMQP channel enabled. I am trying to write a RabbitMQ client program in Java which can connect to AMQP channel in IBM MQ and publish & consume messages. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ clients use the 0.9.1 version of AMQP which is very different to the version supported by IBM MQ (AMQP 1.0) You could use a Qpid Proton client to connect to IBM MQ, one of the MQ Light clients, or anything which supports AMQP 1.0.

Comment: I know RabbitMQ server supports AMQP 1.0 with a plugin and I have updated that successfully. But not sure how that will help me to connect to AMQP channel in IBM MQ server.

Comment: But you asked about RabbitMQ clients - which I think use AMQP 0.9.1 rather than AMQP 1.0? You're right, the RabbitMQ server support for AMQP 1.0 won't help you connect RabbitMQ clients to IBM MQ.

Comment: okay got it! So it is only a server side update and not on client side. So this is impossible as of now?